# Paging and UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is possible to add a pagination for UITableView rows?When the user scrolls vertically the UITableView it change rows!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` for adding more rows at the bottom. This method is called every time before a row is about to be displayed. In the method, check if the row is corresponding to the last item in your data source. If yes, add more rows at the end.

```
if(indexPath.row == [self.items count] - 1) //items is your data source
{
      [self addMoreItems];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making pages in a tableView is not hard, it's just a matter of allowing the table to expand when required.

Use a mutable structure, such as a `NSMutableArray` as your main source of data for the tableView, when the user clicks on the last row (or the row loads, however you want). Get the new data, append it to the array, and then force the tableview to reload.