# UItableView load data 10 10 records on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am getting the data from the web-service and I have to display it in UITableView. But the condition here is I have to display only 10 records initially,then once the user scroll down I have to load more records it contains image also.I tried searching it but didn't get any useful answer.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

display the value,but how will I fetch only 10 records initially ce and then other record based on scroll. Please provide some points or sample code

Comment: What you are looking for is called paging...

Comment: hmm, I have the more than 100 record with image also , I want to load the data on tableview in first 10 records initially, after that user scroll or loaded completely the next 10 records loads automatically how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging and UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458861/paging-and-uitableview)

Comment: Well I mentioned what you are looking for is called paging or pagination. Do a search for UITableView paging or UITableView pagination and you will get dozens of results and sample code

Comment: I looking for the pagination in uitablview

Answer (score 3):

In your backend link keep an ' index' field. When index=0, get the 10 records from backed then increment index to 1, get another 10 records,etc...

keep the code also to call link when scroll the tableView at the end ,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

    NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 0) {
        index =index +1;
        // Call your link here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you could always check if the current row equals the count of `your data - 1:`

```
if(indexPath.row == tableData.count - 1)
{
    [self getMoreData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume that in your web service you will get page number and 10
   record as per page
2. when you scroll in tablview it will call willDisplayCell and check
   current Array count.
3. if your scroll reach equal to array count or last record it will request data again with page number.

---

```
//Declare variable 
 NSInteger currentPageNumber;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == arrData.count-1) {
         currentPageNumber++;
         //Call your Webservice
     }
}

-(void)webserviceCall{
    //pass page number in your web service you will get data with page number 
   // After getting data from web service you need to add data in your array, so you will have total records. 
 if([[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 1){
      [arrData addObjectsFromArray:arrData];
    }

  }
```

Comment: okay if i want to handle the data in locally, I mean I get 500 data from server for time consuming , in here I want to load 10 10 data on scroll how will handle this\

Comment: you can add your received data in local database so you will get when you don't have an internet connection from local.